# разный ответ mySQL на одинаковые команды

Tags: mysql, ssh

С помощью терминала установил связь с удаленным сервером MySQL через SSH, авторизовался.
Ввожу команды и получаю разные ответы:

```
mysql> show databases // результат - перевод на новую пустую строку
    -> show databases;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'show databases' at line 2
mysql> show databases;
+-------------------------------------------------+
| Database                                        |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| information_schema                              |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

почему, что не так и как надо? заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Команда заканчивается точкой с запятой. В первом случае вы ввели:

```
show databases
show databases;
```

Т.е. с точки зрения `mysql` вы ввели команду `show databases show databases`, которую он естественно не знает.

Во втором случае команда `show databases;` - т.е. все правильно.